# Decoding Differences Between Scikit-learn SVM and libsvm in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, svm, libsvm

I am moving much of my neuroimaging coding over to Python from Matlab and so I am switching from using libsvm in Matlab to using Scikit-learn SVM in Python. Just to make sure I am not changing anything substantive about my analyses, I am experimenting with the two implementations and trying to see whether I can get them to yield identical results.

In Python I am using:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear',C=1,probability=True)
```

In Matlab (libsvm) I am using:

```
clf = libsvmtrain(svm_training_labels,svm_training_vectors,['-t 0 -b 1 -c 1'])
```

When I run the SVM using these two different ways using simulated data, I get subtly different results, even though I have fixed all of the parameters of the SVMs to be the same using input arguments (linear classifier, C=1, use probability estimates), and even though all the other default parameters seem to be the same across these functions (tolerance = .001, both using shrinking heuristics by default). Any idea of what could possibly be leading to differences in the results?

EDIT:

It'd be helpful to mention how much the results diverged.

One simulation I ran was designed to be absurdly difficult--it yielded 40% accuracy for Matlab libsvm, and 44% accuracy for scikit-learn svm (binary classification, chance = 50%). In this simulation, the two SVMs agreed in their predictions only 18% of the time (in other words, they were both not only guessing below chance, but they nearly always gave opposite guesses compared to each other).

The other simulation was easier, yielding 68% accuracy for Matlab libsvm, and 67% accuracy for scikit-learn SVM. In this simulation, the two SVMs agreed in their predictions 97% of the time. So even though they often got it wrong, they tended to make the same wrong guesses.

Comment: Are you able to share a sample of your results? It would be interesting to see how different they are.

Comment: Edited to include this

Comment: Would any other data be helpful?